# Information theory -- on-topic?

Tags: discussion

I had added this as a comment to another question about what the site should consider an on-topic question and encouraged by others thought it merited its own question.

Given that Claude Shannon seemed to consider himself in the field of signal processing, will/should the community consider the broader range of information theory questions as on-topic?

I've found that those with backgrounds in signal processing will often have clearer insights to broader information theory questions than more general mathematicians or statisticians.

Thoughts?

Comment: I appreciate the up votes on the question, but remain unclear on whether or not the community will consider the broader range of information theory questions as on-topic.  How does the decision get made?

Answer (score 9):

I would consider information theory on-topic. The field intertwines with signal processing quite a bit. My only concern is whether or not there are enough frequent visitors that have sufficient expertise in the field to give good answers.

Comment: I agree completely. Information theory should definitely be considered on topic here. If not here, where else?